# Looking for a start-to-finish how-to on Laravel 5.2 OAuth2 implementation

Tags: rest, authentication, oauth, laravel-5, oauth-2.0

Quick background: I'm fairly experienced with PHP, but needed to build my first RESTful API. I figured I'd try Laravel (5.2) and am starting to feel pretty comfortable with it.

I started adding auth to my project over the weekend and I am really struggling to get it working. I got the basic Laravel Auth middleware working quickly, but I think I need to be using OAuth2 for production (I will be building a mobile app that will connect up to this server). I'm using the Luca Degasperi OAuth2 package, which seems to be pretty popular.

I reviewed the actual documentation: https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/tree/master/docs#readme)

I also went through this tutorial: https://medium.com/@mshanak/laravel-5-token-based-authentication-ae258c12cfea#.5lszb67xb

And, most recently, I found this thread about the need to seed the OAuth tables before anything will work: https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/issues/56

That's all great, but there are some minor differences in the most recent distribution of Laravel. For example, /app/Http/Kernel.php is slightly different from what's shown in some of the examples I found because it now uses middleware groups. I thought I handled those differences correctly (I added the OAuthExceptionHandlerMiddleware class to the 'web' section of $middlewareGroups instead of $middleware). I got my seeder working (the current oauth_scopes table only allows you to supply a description, so I had to slim down what was provided in the third link above).

If I put a test route in my 'web' group in routes.php, I would have thought this would require OAuth because I added OAuth to the 'web' middleware group in Kernel.php. That's not the case. My route works with no authentication if I do that.

I then explicitly added the OAuth middleware to my test route as follows:

```
Route::get('tests/events', ['middleware' => 'oauth', function() {
    $events = App\Event::get();
    return response()->json($events);
}]);
```

That causes a 500 error ("ErrorException in OAuth2ServerServiceProvider.php line 126: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given").

I'm to feel pretty lost. Each of these packages seems to be shifting so quickly that there's no *complete* documentation on how to get this up and running.

What else do I need to do to get this functioning?

Comment: I've gotten a little closer, but it's still not working. I don't think you need to seed the scopes table. For the route I provided in my original post, you need `'uses' => function ()` not just `function ()`. Also, in oauth2.php, I'm getting closer to working by using `'callback' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@validate'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following link is what finally got me un-stuck:

https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/blob/master/docs/authorization-server/password.md

Now that I have it working, I'll try and make this a complete how-to FOR PASSWORD GRANT TYPES ONLY. I didn't play with other grant types. So this assumes you're building something like a RESTful API where users will connect to it with a client app that you're going to build. So users will create a user account in your system and then when they send a REST request, the OAuth2 package will authenticate them and send them a token to stay logged in.

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and already had the basic Auth package up and running. Be advised that a lot of these steps seem to change even with incremental releases of Laravel or the OAuth2 package.

---

The first part of getting this working is fairly well documented already (https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/tree/master/docs#readme), but here's a summary just in case...

Edit the `require` section of your `composer.json` file to look something like this:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel": "5.1.*"
},
```

Run `composer update` to download the package.

Open your `config/app.php` file and add the following two lines to the end of the `providers` section:

```
LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Storage\FluentStorageServiceProvider::class,
LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\OAuth2ServerServiceProvider::class,
```

Also in `config/app.php`, add this line to the `aliases` array:

```
'Authorizer' => LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Facades\Authorizer::class,
```

---

Now we start to do things a little differently from the documentation to accommodate the current version of Laravel...

Open `app/Http/Kernel.php`. Laravel now uses groups and it didn't used to. Update your `$middlewareGroups` to look like this:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,

        //Added for OAuth2 Server
        \LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Middleware\OAuthExceptionHandlerMiddleware::class,

        //Commented out for OAuth2 Server
        //\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```

Also in `app/Http/kernel.php`, update `$routeMiddleware` to look like this:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,

    //Added for OAuth2 Server
    'oauth' => \LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Middleware\OAuthMiddleware::class,
    'oauth-user' => \LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Middleware\OAuthUserOwnerMiddleware::class,
    'oauth-client' => \LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Middleware\OAuthClientOwnerMiddleware::class,
    'check-authorization-params' => \LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Middleware\CheckAuthCodeRequestMiddleware::class,
    'csrf' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
];
```

You now have to set up your grant types. You used to do this all in one place in `config\oauth2.php` using an array with a closure for `callback`. With the most recent version of the OAuth2 server package, you can't use a closure for `callback` anymore. It has to be a string. So your `grant_types` should look something like this:

```
'grant_types' => [
    'password' => [
        'class' => '\League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\PasswordGrant',
        'callback' => '\App\PasswordGrantVerifier@verify',
        'access_token_ttl' => 3600
    ]
]
```

`access_token_ttl` is the duration that an auth token will be good for (in seconds). The main package documentation uses 3600 (1 hour) by default. You might want to try 604800 (1 week) instead -- at least during testing.

You now need to create the `PasswordGrantVerifier` class and `verify` method that you just called in the code section above. So you create a file `App/PasswordGrantVerifier.php` and use the following code (which is basically what used to go in the closure for `callback`).

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class PasswordGrantVerifier
{
    public function verify($username, $password)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'email'    => $username,
            'password' => $password,
        ];

        if (Auth::once($credentials)) {
            return Auth::user()->id;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

You will need at least one row in the `oauth_clients` table before OAuth2 will work. You can insert something manually or create a seeder. To create a seeder, modify `database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php` and add the following to the end of the `run()` method:

```
$this->call(OAuthClientsTableSeeder::class);
```

Now create a file called `database/seeds/OAuthClientsTableSeeder.php` and enter something like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class OAuthClientsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        //Add sample users
        $oAuthClients = array(
            array(
                'id' => 'TEST_ENVIRONMENT',
                'secret' => 'b17b0ec30dbb6e1726a17972afad008be6a3e4a5',
                'name' => 'TEST_ENVIRONMENT'
            )
        );

        foreach ($oAuthClients as $oAuthClient) {
            App\OAuthClient::create($oAuthClient);
        }
    }
}
```

Run `php artisan vendor:publish` to publish the package configuration and migrations. Run `php artisan migrate` to set up the billion-or-so new tables for OAuth. Run `php artisan db:seed` to seed your database.

You can now set up some test routes in `app\Http\routes.php`. They should look something like this:

```
Route::post('oauth/access_token', function() {
    return Response::json(Authorizer::issueAccessToken());
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'oauth'], function () {

    Route::get('authroute', function() {
        //OAuth will be required to access this route
    });

    Route::post('postwithauth', function(Request $request) {
        $userID = Authorizer::getResourceOwnerId();
        $input = $request->input();
        return response()->json(array('userID' => $userID, 'input' => $input));
    });

});

Route::get('noauthroute', function () {
    //No authorization will be required to access this route
});
```

Pay close attention to the `postwithauth` route I included above. The OAuth2 package recently changed how you access the user's ID and it took me quite a while to figure out how to get it.

Now that it's time for testing, point your browser to `localhost:8000` (or whatever the path is for your test environment) and create a user account for yourself (this step just uses the standard Laravel Auth package).

Go into your HTTP client (I'm currently using [Paw](http://luckymarmot.com/paw) and I like it). Go to request->authorization->OAuth2 to set up authorization for the route you're going to test. For `Grant Type`, select `Resource Owner Password Credentials`. If you used the seed example I provided above, the `Client ID` is `TEST_ENVIRONMENT`, the `Client Secret` is `b17b0ec30dbb6e1726a17972afad008be6a3e4a5`, enter the username (email) and password you created through the web Auth interface, your `Access Toekn URL` will be something like `localhost:8000/oauth/access_token` (depending on how you set up your test environment), leave `Scope` blank, and `Token` should say `Bearer`. Click on `Get Access Token` then say `Use Access Token` when prompted.

That should be it!